# YouTube won't playback my videos in high resolution

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, youtube-studio

I've uploaded some 1080x1920p (portrait layout) MP4 H.264 videos to my YouTube channel, but YouTube only allows playback on them at a max resolution of 480p. **How can I get them to allow playback at the original resolution?**

[image]

The videos were recorded with an LG H932 Android phone, running software version H93230d.

The codec info, according to VLC:

```
Stream 0
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Language: English
Type: Video
Video resolution: 1920x1080
Buffer dimensions: 1920x1088
Frame rate: 30.011402
Decoded format: 
Orientation: Left bottom
Color primaries: ITU-R BT.601 (525 lines, 60 Hz)
Color transfer function: ITU-R BT.709
Color space: ITU-R BT.601 Range
Chroma location: Left

Stream 1
Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)
Language: English
Type: Audio
Channels: Stereo
Sample rate: 48000 Hz
Bits per sample: 32
```

Based on YouTube's [Recommended upload encoding settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en), I tried using [ffmpeg to move the moov atom to the beginning of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282151/1995714), using the command below, and re-uploading, but it didn't make any difference.

`ffmpeg -i input_video_file.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -movflags faststart output_video_file.mp4`

In case it matters, I have no subscribers on my YouTube channel, and the videos are set to private visibility.

Comment: if you right-click the YouTube-player and select "stats for nerds", what does it say for current/optimal resolution?

Comment: @LeoWattenberg weird, now I see that I *can* get the higher resolution on the YouTube desktop website, but not in the YouTube Android app. In both cases, the highest available manually-selectable "Quality" settings only go up to 480p. With 480p quality selected, in each player, "stats for nerds" says... (1) On the YouTube website, "Current / Optimal Res: 608x1080@30 / 608x1080@30". (2) In the app, "Video format: 135  270x480@30". In both cases the "nerds" resolution appears to be correct (*not* 480p on desktop). So on the website the options are wrong, and in the app they're limited.

Comment: I guess I'll file a bug report.